# margin or padding not working using <merge tag android

Tags: android, xml

I am using merge tag in custom view and trying to set layout_marginTop or paddingTop on parent view, but doesn't work. Here is my code
file name: my_view.xml

```
<merge
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android_layout_marginTop="17dp" >  // This margin is lost!
    // content here  ...
</merge>
```

So in My custom view file, MyView.java, I just inflate this my_view.xml. But the android_layout_marginTop information is lost.

```
public class MyView {
    private void initViews() {
        View view = LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
        // get rest views
    }
}
```

I have tried to set the margins and paddings in the code using LayoutParams, but still not working.
Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<merge>` tag is not a `View`, so trying to set a margin on it isn't going to work.

It looks like you're following the "Compound Control" pattern, where you create a subclass of some common `ViewGroup` (a `LinearLayout`, perhaps) and then inflate some other standard `View`s into it. If that is the case...

Remove all of the `layout_` attributes from your `<merge>` tag, and instead place them on your custom view's tag, wherever you use it in your screen's layout. Something like this:

```
<com.example.stackoverflow.MyView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Hi Ben, where can I read more about "Compound Control" pattern?

Comment: @PetarMarijanovic check out developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html